# Haskell "No instance for" type error in simple code

Tags: haskell, types, type-conversion

***I am a really big noob to Haskell.***

I have this code:

```
4 sieve n i = if i < n
5             then
6                 do {
7                  innerSieve n;
8                  sieve n (i + 1);
9                 }
10             else -1
11 
12 innerSieve n = return n
13 
14 --innerSieve n i j = [x | x <- [i..n], x `mod` j == 0]
```

and I have this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( sieve.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> sieve 10 2

<interactive>:1:1:
No instance for (Num (m0 b0))
  arising from a use of `sieve'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (m0 b0))
In the expression: sieve 10 2
In an equation for `it': it = sieve 10 2
*Main>
```

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to understand what it means by "No instance for (Num (m0 b0))." What in the world is a m0 b0?

I thought this might help:

```
*Main> :t sieve
sieve :: (Ord a, Num a, Num (m b), Monad m) => a -> a -> m b
*Main>
```

EDIT:
I am trying to recreate the sieve of erastothenes by making a recursive function with a list comprehension, basically. I also want to -understand- everything in the code.

Comment: At first. In `if ... then do ... else -1` expression after `then` (`do ...`) and `else` (`-1`) have different types. `do ...` has monadic type (`m b`). And type of `-1` implements the typeclass `Num` (in other words it's just a number).

What did your code should do?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do... Why is sieve monadic ? What monad do you intend to use it into ? As for the error, it means that both branches of your if are incompatible : the then results in "sieve n (i+1)" which has to be monadic since it's the last element of a do-block so say of type "Monad m => m a" and the else results in "-1" which is clearly a number. Number literals are polymorphic in Haskell, here the compiler tries to convert "-1" to the type "m a" and find that it doesn't know how to do that (it only knows for Num instances, that is Int, Integer, Float...).

Comment: Are you trying to replicate the behavior of the list comprehension you comment out?

Comment: What type do you want `sieve` to have?

Comment: You're trying to write imperatively without understanding the language. Haskell is a completely different type of language than what you're likely used to. It takes some time to understand, but you have to forget everything about imperative languages first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you almost certainly dont want to use a `do` block in your code where you do.  `do` is for `Monads` and should be avoided when learning Haskell, and is probably inappropriate since the only `Monad` here is `[]` which would ignore *any* definition of `innerSieve`.  Haskell code describes **values** and types in terms of other values and types.  Haskell programs dont tell the computer what to do, they tell it what **is**. This is a radical way of thinking, but a very powerful one. `do` notation is a special syntax for handling monads which are a special kind of value that can be used to encode computations (including imperative computations and state transitions) cleanly and efficiently, but it requires a broad understanding of Haskell to use well.

My advice to Haskell newbies is "Avoid monads and `do` notation until you have mastered: recursion, higher order functions, and typeclasses.  You dont need `do` to test your programs (use GHCi), so learn the real functional way of thinking.  Try to program such that your programs dont `do` anything!"

So, how would you go about writing a sieve of Eratosthenes in Haskell?  There are many elegant ways.  Warning: spoilers ahead.  If you want to do this by yourself stop reading

You have commented out:

```
innerSieve n i j = [x | x <- [i..n], x `mod` j == 0]
```

I'm not sure what the point of `n` and `i` are here.  It would be more elegant to write

```
innerSieve j ls = [x | x <- ls, x `mod` j == 0]
```

which has the type

```
innerSieve :: Integral x => x -> [x] -> [x]
```

so, in other words, it takes a list a value of some type `x` such that that type can be treated like an integer, and returns all the integral multiples of the original value.

You could use this to write the sieve of Eratosthenes, but a better way would be to get all the values that **are not** multiples.  The reason is that, then you can just stack a bunch of these together to produce your full prime sieve

```
innerSieve j ls = [x | x <- ls, x `mod` j /= 0]
```

Here the `/=` is Haskell's way of saying "not equal".  Cool, so lets build a prime sieve out of this

```
sieve (x:xs) = x : sieve (innerSieve x xs)
sieve [] = []
```

What does this say? well it takes a list of numbers, and gives you back a new list consisting of the first of those numbers, and the sieve applied to the rest of those numbers except for those that are multiples of the first one.  The `(x:xs)` is a *pattern* that matches any list other than the empty list, binding `x` with the head of the list, and `xs` with the tail of the list.  `[]` is a pattern that matches any empty list.

Finally, you can define the infinite list of all primes

```
primes = sieve [2..]
```

The expression `[2..]` generates the list `2,3,4,5,6,7,etc` going on forever. Looks scary (infinite lists), but is okay because of Haskell's famed lazy evaluation.  To get the nth prime you can say:

```
nthPrime n = primes !! (n - 1)
```

which just indexes into the list of primes.  Haskell will only compute the minimum needed to return the result, so this function will terminate even though `primes` is infinitely long

or to get all the primes up to a number

```
primesUpToN n = take n primes
```

so, your entire code base ends up being:

```
sieve [] = []
sieve (x:xs) = x : sieve (innerSieve x xs) where
   innerSieve j ls = [x | x <- ls, x `mod` j /= 0]

primes = sieve [2..]

nthPrime n = primes !! (n - 1)

primesUpToN n = take n primes
```

This isn't really the sieve of Eratosthenes, since you aren't "marking off" values.  But, this sieve is actually "better" insofar as it is both faster and defines the set of **all** primes, rather than those up to a number.  It is not how you should ever actually go about generating primes, but in 6 lines of code (most of which are unnecessary), it is hard to argue that mutation or looping makes things simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Your inner `do` block has a monadic type. This makes the entire result of `sieve` have a monadic type of `(Monad m) => m b`. The `else` branch of your `if` statement returns `-1`, so we know it also has a numeric type. This makes the result of your function `(Num (m b), Monad m) => m b`. This is very clearly wrong.

I can't figure out what your function is trying to accomplish, so I'm not sure where exactly you went wrong. I would recommend writing explicit type annotations on your functions, to express exactly what you're expecting each function to do. That will, at a minimum, give you better error messages, because instead of saying that the inferred type doesn't make sense, it can point you to exactly what expression doesn't match the explicit type.

BTW, you might find the `if` statement is better expressed as

```
sieve n i
    | i < n     = -- contents of the then block
    | otherwise = -1
```

Comment: basically, I want to call innerSieve, then I want to recurse sieve again.

Comment: *Why* do you call `innerSieve`? What do you want to do with the value it computes?

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the sieve of erastothenes. I thought it would be a simple challenge until I realized that Haskell has no looping constructs. I surmised that I need a recursive function with a list comprehension

Answer (score 4):

Haskell is a functional language. This especially means, that you don't tell the compiler *Do A then do B* but rather *calculate A* – You don't tell the compiler in what order to do things, rather you tell it what you want to know. You can think of that as having only one (`return`) statement. Thus, you need to rewrite your code to fit to this paradigma.

The `do` statement is for a special construct called *monad* that essentially allows stateful actions (such as printing to the screen) in a consistent manners. You don't need it.

As the others already showed you, you can do something like this. The pipe (`|`) is called *pattern guard* and essentially works like an If-then-else:

```
sieve n i | i < n     = --result if condition is met
          | otherwise = -1
```

Remember that you *can't change the values of variables*. You may need to rewrite your `innerSieve` to return something.

Answer (score 0):

Not only does this give a type error:

```
do {
   innerSieve n;
   sieve n (i + 1);
   }
```

But it has the exact same value as

```
do {
   sieve n (i + 1);
   }
```

You have called a function "innerSeive", but then not done anything with the value.
If you would like to compute a value and then use the value in the next operation, use the `(>>=)` operator (sugared as `let x = innerseive n; f2 n;` within a `do` block).
However, for these mathematical functions, stay far, far away from `do`, `let`, `(>>=)`, etc.